# How can I move my icons to the left in my HTML layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a similar version of Twitter using HTML+CSS I'm trying to move my icons to the left like they are in Twitter but for some reason they don't.

You can look to the photo or run the code

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1, 5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 13%;
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.linkes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkes a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 8px 25px 8px 8px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.linkes a i {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.linkes a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(47, 51, 54);
  border-radius: 9999px;
}

.linkes a:first-child {
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.linkes i:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
  width: 90%;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.main a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.twettp {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.an {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ah {
  color: rgb(110, 118, 125);
}

main {
  width: 71;
  height: 100;
  margin-left: 29%;
}

.main-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-feed {
  width: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
}

.home-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.new-tweet {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

.new-tweet .twettp {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.new-tweet-action {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

.new-tweet input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.new-tweet-action ul li {
  margin-right: 12px;
  color: #1c88d2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet-action.button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 35%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WP.css">
    <title>bwetter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="linkes">
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            flutter_dash
        </i>
    
    </a>

    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            home
        </i>
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
           tag
        </i>
        <span>Explore</span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            notifications
        </i>
        <span>Notifications</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            email
        </i>
        <span>Messages</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            bookmark_border
        </i>
        <span>Bookmark</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            list_alt
        </i>
        <span>List</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            person
        </i>
        <span>Profile</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" >
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            more
        </i>
        <span>More</span>
    </a>
    <button class="button">wes</button>
    <div class="main">
        <a href="">
            <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="name">
                <span class="an">wesam</span>
                <span class="ah">wasg</span>
            </div>
            <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                more_horiz
            </i>

        </a>
    </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="main-flex">
            <div class="main-feed">
                <div class="home-bar">
                    <span>Home</span>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                        auto_awesome
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="side-feed">
                    <div class="new-tweet">
                        <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg">
                        <div class="new-tweet">
                            <div class="new-tweet-action">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="What's happening">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                        image
                                    </i>
                            
                                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    gif_box
                                </i>
                                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    poll
                                </i>
                                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    sentiment_satisfied
                                </i>
                                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    event
                                </i>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                            <button class="button">wes</button>
                       
    
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

- Allowing the `.new-tweet-action` flex container to wrap children onto a new line.
- Applying `margin-right: auto` to the `.new-tweet-action ul` element to push any subsequent sibling elements to the right most of the container.
- Overriding the `.new-tweet-action .button` element's `width` so that it is smaller than `90%` so that the previous `ul` element can sit alongside without wrapping.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1, 5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 13%;
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.linkes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkes a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 8px 25px 8px 8px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.linkes a i {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.linkes a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(47, 51, 54);
  border-radius: 9999px;
}

.linkes a:first-child {
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.linkes i:first-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
  width: 90%;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.main a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.twettp {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.an {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ah {
  color: rgb(110, 118, 125);
}

main {
  width: 71;
  height: 100;
  margin-left: 29%;
}

.main-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-feed {
  width: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
}

.home-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.new-tweet {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

.new-tweet .twettp {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.new-tweet-action {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.new-tweet input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.new-tweet-action ul {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.new-tweet-action ul li {
  margin-right: 12px;
  color: #1c88d2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet-action.button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 35%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.new-tweet-action .button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="WP.css">
  <title>bwetter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="linkes">
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            flutter_dash
        </i>

      </a>

      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            home
        </i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>

      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
           tag
        </i>
        <span>Explore</span>
      </a>

      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            notifications
        </i>
        <span>Notifications</span>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            email
        </i>
        <span>Messages</span>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            bookmark_border
        </i>
        <span>Bookmark</span>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            list_alt
        </i>
        <span>List</span>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            person
        </i>
        <span>Profile</span>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
            more
        </i>
        <span>More</span>
      </a>
      <button class="button">wes</button>
      <div class="main">
        <a href="">
          <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="name">
            <span class="an">wesam</span>
            <span class="ah">wasg</span>
          </div>
          <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                more_horiz
            </i>

        </a>
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-flex">
      <div class="main-feed">
        <div class="home-bar">
          <span>Home</span>
          <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                        auto_awesome
                    </i>
        </div>
        <div class="side-feed">
          <div class="new-tweet">
            <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg">
            <div class="new-tweet">
              <div class="new-tweet-action">
                <input type="text" placeholder="What's happening">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                        image
                                    </i>

                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    gif_box
                                </i>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    poll
                                </i>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    sentiment_satisfied
                                </i>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                    event
                                </i>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="button">wes</button>


              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but can you explain the problem for because I didn't understand the problem

Comment: Your original code did not tell `.new-tweet-action` to wrap its children, so all the child elements have to be on one line. Since the `<input>` element is first, it will be the element on the left, with the `<ul>` with the icons following after.

Answer (score 0):

i Checked Your Code Right Now and it Looks Like Your having Problem With Aligning Your icons To The Left Side Like Twitter icons, Please Add The `class="icon-pack"` into ul after the `<input type="text" placeholder="What's happening">` Now paste This Code into Your CSS File, Now it Should Work Like a Charm :)

```html
.icon-pack {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 90px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1, 5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 13%;
    width: 29%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.linkes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.linkes a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px 8px;
    width: fit-content;
}

.linkes a i {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.linkes a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(47, 51, 54);
    border-radius: 9999px;
}

.linkes a:first-child {
    padding: 8px 8px;
}

.linkes i:first-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.button {
    background-color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
    width: 90%;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.main a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.twettp {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 70%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.an {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.ah {
    color: rgb(110, 118, 125);
}

main {
    width: 71;
    height: 100;
    margin-left: 29%;
}

.main-flex {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-feed {
    width: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(47, 51, 54);
}

.home-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 55%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.new-tweet {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 4px 16px;
}

.new-tweet .twettp {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.new-tweet-action {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.new-tweet input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}

.new-tweet-action ul li {
    margin-right: 12px;
    color: #1c88d2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new-tweet-action.button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 35%;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.icon-pack {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 90px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>bwetter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="linkes">
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    flutter_dash
                </i>

            </a>

            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    home
                </i>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>

            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    tag
                </i>
                <span>Explore</span>
            </a>

            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    notifications
                </i>
                <span>Notifications</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    email
                </i>
                <span>Messages</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    bookmark_border
                </i>
                <span>Bookmark</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    list_alt
                </i>
                <span>List</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    person
                </i>
                <span>Profile</span>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                    more
                </i>
                <span>More</span>
            </a>
            <button class="button">wes</button>
            <div class="main">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="name">
                        <span class="an">wesam</span>
                        <span class="ah">wasg</span>
                    </div>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                        more_horiz
                    </i>

                </a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="main-flex">
            <div class="main-feed">
                <div class="home-bar">
                    <span>Home</span>
                    <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                        auto_awesome
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="side-feed">
                    <div class="new-tweet">
                        <img class="twettp" src="S.jpg">
                        <div class="new-tweet">
                            <div class="new-tweet-action">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="What's happening">
                                <ul class="icon-pack">
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                            image
                                        </i>

                                        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                            gif_box
                                        </i>
                                        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                            poll
                                        </i>
                                        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                            sentiment_satisfied
                                        </i>
                                        <i class="material-icons-outlined">
                                            event
                                        </i>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <button class="button">wes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but can you explain the problem for because I didn't understand the problem –

Comment: Sure, here we first added Class to ul after input text and then we add some css to it, display: flex, for displaying the icons flex able and then we added margin-right: auto To add some Spacing To the Right Side of The icons and then we added margin-top: 90px For bring icons down, after that we use position: absolute this will help us to move our elements freely, i hope you Understand